# Problem with Flask and static path url in Pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

I create

```
static url = /assets/ 
directory= /home/Domemakarov2013/webapp_ML/assets
```

and my css file is in
`/home/Domemakarov2013/webapp_ML/assets/dist/css/bootstrap.css`

then in `main.html` i call

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for ('assets', filename='dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">`
```

I got error from server 500 Internal server, but if i delete this line it will be working. How can i fix this? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't forget to accept an answer (tick the check-mark next to an answer) if it answers your question. In this way your question stops from showing up as _unanswered_. Also up-vote good answers. – As you're starting out here, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you look at the error log, which is linked from the "Web" tab on PythonAnywhere, you will see the errors that your code is generating.  The most recent error will be at the bottom of the file.  If you add that error message to your post, it will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for ('assets', filename='dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for ('.assets', filename='dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
```

Comment: View the source code in your browser, to see what url is actually rendering on the page.

Answer (score 0):

`url_for` takes `endpoint` and `filename`

```
url_for(endpoint, filename="filename")
```

use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for ('assets', filename='dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">`
```

instead of:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for ('/assets/', filename='dist/css/bootstrap.css') }}">`
```

know more about flask `url` here:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for